# Android Service make popup in app or outside of app

Tags: android, service, popup, android-alertdialog

This may be a compounded question as there are two concepts I don't yet understand that may be related.

I want a Service to popup a custom alert dialog.

I dont know

a) if I can popup an alert dialog from a service (simply haven't tried yet, dont know what context to give it)

and

b) how a service can interact with an activity

and

c) if I can popup an alert dialog from outside the app (it is a niche application, the users will be expecting popup alerts)

Insight appreciated on the best approach to this problem!

Comment: You don't really state what your alert is supposed to be used for, but have you considered simply using a [status bar notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want a Service to popup a custom alert dialog.

This is generally a bad idea.

> if I can popup an alert dialog from a service

No, sorry.

> how a service can interact with an activity

A service can start an activity, or send a broadcast `Intent` that is picked up by an activity, or send a `Message` to a `Messenger` supplied by an activity, or respond to methods call by a bound activity, or...

> it is a niche application, the users will be expecting popup alerts

First, make this configurable. Unless you have precisely one user -- you -- you do not know what your users will want. Having something pop up on the screen and take over the foreground is very intrusive, and only a very few apps will warrant that behavior.

I would make it configurable between a `Notification` (as Mr. Madsen suggests in the comment) or a dialog-themed `Activity`.

Comment: CommonsWare, let me re-iterate, the users that will install this app will not have a choice and will be subject to the will of the client.  So things that are `generally a bad idea` and `what the user wants` are totally irrelevant here. I tried to make that clear and am now just determining the extent of what is possible within the SDK. But again, this is a niche application and users will expect it to interrupt any other application like a phone call would.

Comment: So the service itself can call an activity that shows an alert dialog

Comment: @RD: "the users that will install this app will not have a choice and will be subject to the will of the client" -- no, they are not. They can choose to not use the app. They can choose not to use their device. They can choose to find a new employer/country/whatever is forcing them to use this device and app. And so on. "So the service itself can call an activity that shows an alert dialog" -- it would be better for the service to simply start a dialog-themed activity.

Comment: thanks, the dialog themed activity got me in the right direction, BUT when it loads from outside of the app, it pops up the alert dialog activity, but the app is in the visible background too, I dont want the app to come up in all conditions, how do I tweak this?

Comment: @RD: try adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to the `Intent` you use to start the dialog-themed activity.